# Config Action Bar in List Fragment in Android Project

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I am following the book and I made a list view using fragment. But I can't config the Action Bar in that application because now I want to add option menu to action bar. Here is the my code in [github](https://github.com/rasikag/CriminalIntent). I am really grateful if someone can point me where should I change my code.

I try to figure out what is different in my code with new project template but couldn't figure it out.

Code :

This is the base activity to inherit to all Activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;


// universal fragment activity
public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = createFragment();
            manager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the layout file that above fragment activity used by `[R.id.fragmentContainer]` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer">


</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the activity that host the list activity

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;


public class CrimeListActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {
        return new CrimeListFragment();
    }
}
```

Here is the list fragment activity :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class CrimeListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ArrayList<Crime> mCrimes;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.crimes_title);
        mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes();
        CrimeAdapter adapter = new CrimeAdapter(mCrimes);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // get the Crime from the adapter
        Crime c = ((CrimeAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);
        // start an instance of CrimePagerActivity
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CrimePagerActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(CrimeFragment.EXTRA_CRIME_ID, c.getId());
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        ((CrimeAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_crime_list,menu);
    }

    private class CrimeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Crime> {
        public CrimeAdapter(ArrayList<Crime> crimes) {
            super(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, crimes);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // if we weren't given a view, inflate one
            if (null == convertView) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                        .inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, null);
            }

            // configure the view for this Crime
            Crime c = getItem(position);

            TextView titleTextView =
                    (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_titleTextView);
            titleTextView.setText(c.getTitle());
            TextView dateTextView =
                    (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_dateTextView);
            dateTextView.setText(c.getDate().toString());
            CheckBox solvedCheckBox =
                    (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_solvedCheckBox);
            solvedCheckBox.setChecked(c.isSolved());

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the layout that used by `CrimeAdapter inner class`  `[R.layout.list_item_crime]` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/crime_list_item_solvedCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crime_list_item_titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/crime_list_item_solvedCheckBox"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:text="Crime Title"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crime_list_item_dateTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/crime_list_item_titleTextView"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/crime_list_item_solvedCheckBox"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:text="Crime Date"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So where should I change to added a Action bar ??

Comment: please post some example activity or point us in some direction, don't just give a link to your whole project.

Comment: @inner_class7 Can you please check now. I added code example now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few simple changes first edit to styles.xml:

```
<!-- Changed your app theme -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

then updated SingleFragmentActivity.java to extend AppCompatActivity:

```
public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = createFragment();
            manager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

then created a menu_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Settings"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

And then have CrimeListActivity inflate and handle options menu clicks:

```
public class CrimeListActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {
        return new CrimeListFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int itemId = item.getItemId();

        if(itemId == R.id.action_settings){

            // Handle the action

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This will only add it to your one CrimeListActivity though. To make the change across the board. You will need to have all Activity classes that don't use SingleFragmentActivity `extend AppCompatActivity`

**Explanation**

Basic Reason why these changes work:

1. `FragmentActivity` does not know about the `ActionBar`, if you would want something that has an `ActionBar` you would need to use the newer but now deprecated `Activity` which extends `FragmentActivity` call `ActionBarActivity`
2. `ActionBarActivity` now deprecated and replaced by `AppCompatActivity` which does know about the `ActionBar` when the correct Theme is Applied in your case `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` solves the case.

Good Luck and happy coding!

Comment: Thank you bro.
It works. Can you please explain a bit what you have done.
I noted that you only change that 'FragmentActivity' to 'AppCompatActivity'.
What is the different of that??

Comment: @rasikag in a little i will give a better explanation but main thing is your theme was AppCompat but your base Activity was FragmentActivity which does not know about the ActionBar

Comment: Thank you. I see the base implementation of the AppCompactActivity.
I did see that it import the import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.